# Specific example of fixed field using Artin's Theorem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, invariant-theory

I'm attempting a question as follows:

> Let $K = \mathbb Q(x,y)$, where $x,y$ are independent transcendentals, and consider the group $G$ of automorphisms generated by
> $$\sigma: \quad x \mapsto y,\quad  y \mapsto -x$$
> $$\tau: \quad x \mapsto x,\quad y \mapsto -y$$
> Show that the fixed field $K^G = L = \mathbb Q(x^2 + y^2, x^2y^2)$.

I get that $G = \langle \sigma, \tau : \sigma^4 = 1, \tau ^2 = 1, \tau\sigma\tau = \sigma^{-1}\rangle \cong D_8$, so by Artin's Theorem, $[K : K^G] = 8$.

However, since $x,y$ are roots of $$f = (T^2 - x^2)(T^2 - y^2) = T^4 - (x^2 + y^2)T^2 + x^2y^2 \in L[T]$$ This gives

$$ [K : L] \le 4 < [K:K^G]$$

which contradicts $K^G = L$. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Seems I assumed "if all elements have degree $\le 4$ then degree of extension is $\le 4$", but this isn't true? Instead, can we say:

$$ [\mathbb Q(x,y) : L] = [\mathbb Q(x,y) : L(x)] [L(x) : L] \le 8 $$

since $[L(x) : L] \le 4$ using $f$, and then $[\mathbb Q(x,y) : L(x)] = 2$ since $y$ is a root of $T^2 - (x^2y^2)/(x^2)$.

And clearly $K^G \subseteq L$, so by dimensions $K^G = L$.

Comment: note that $L[T]/(f)$ doesn't have to contain all the roots of $f$, only one

Comment: @user8268 Good point, that seems to have been the problem. How does the edit look?

Comment: Indeed, $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $L$, but that does not contradict anything. By the primitive element theorem there must exist elements $\rho$ with minimal polynomials of degree $8$. The element $\rho=x+2y$ should work because its orbit under the Galois group has size eight.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible over $L$ (seems likely), then you can conclude that $[L(x):L]=4=[L(y):L]$. But adjoining $y$ to $L(x)$ still gives a quadratic extension, so $[L(x,y):L(x)]=2$, which goes well together with the tower law, as $K=L(x,y)$.

Comment: Compare with the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. It, too has $D_4$ as the Galois group. The splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2, i\root4\of2)$, which can more conveniently be described as $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2, i)$